# Do I need to remove Grub when converting from Ubuntu server to desktop?

Tags: 16.04, server, grub2, system-installation

Do I need to remove the Grub utility when I convert Ubuntu server to Ubuntu desktop in a dual boot laptop?

Comment: Ubuntu still boots with grub2. It is the same grub2 whether server or any flavor of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using legacy BIOS, the Grub boot strap loader resides in the first 512 bytes (bytes, not megabytes or gigabytes) of `sda` (usually).

The first 512 bytes on the drive is called the Master Boot Record (MBR) but grub also reads `initrd.img` (about 50 Megabytes) from `/boot` directory of `sda` (usually).

Grub is agnostic and doesn't care if your `/boot` directory was setup by  Ubuntu 12, 14, 16, generic, low-latency or server.

Currently your Ubuntu Server sets up `/boot` directory for grub. After installing Ubuntu Desktop it will setup the `/boot` directory for grub. Both versions of Ubuntu understand what grub needs to see and sets up the boot strap loader and `/boot` directory accordingly.

Both Server and Desktop versions contain the same grub code embedded within. They both use the `sudo update-grub` command to setup your grub menu. Both use the same `sudo update-initramfs -u` command to create a new grub `initrd.img` file whenever you make changes to plymouth, lvm, init-top hooks, etc.

Windows of course is a different beast which is why you must always install Windows first and Ubuntu second.